# Do some Stack Exchange sites have longer minimum question lengths than others?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, quality-filter, character-limit

I'd imagine that some of them where a large percent of short questions are low-quality, but that there are others (like Unix) where short questions aren't necessarily low-quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no fundamental difference between sites which makes short questions more or less appropriate.  The [How-to-ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page is the same across the network.

It's possible that the Unix community may be more flexible on these rules than others (Skeptics comes to mind as a site which has specific requirements for new posts), but great questions have the same requirements everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Only [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (and [its Meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)).

The minimum allowed length for the body of a question is set to 30 characters network-wide, but it's set to 20 on Stack Overflow in Japanese and its Meta. (Some other character limits are lower there as well.)

Comment: Is the Japanese override also true for answers?

Comment: I was not able to find any meta posts about minimum character requirement being reduced to 20 at SOja. (By the way, I am not a CM .., sorry if I disappoint you in any way .)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Doesn't look like it. The site setting for that is just set to 30 network-wide.